# Underground vehicle case

Tags: story-identification, crime

I'm trying to remember the title of a young adult science fiction adventure novel or novella, probably from the late 50s up to early 70s, set in (then) present or not too distant future. It starts with the mysterious disappearance of an escaped convict surrounded by police in a small forest. The accidental witnesses were some young boys who were then kidnapped in a subterranean vehicle (a drill, a mole), which was later used to steal gold treasure from an underground bank vault.
(all vague memory:)

Comment: Something about this makes me think of the Mad Scientist Club.

Comment: @Andrew: The main focus or motif of the story is the machine capable of transporting under the Earth's surface by the means of drilling. Unfortunately I can't find such a device in the plot summaries of your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally discovered a very little known Welsh author, [John Dolben Mackworth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q76064083), who published [The Menace of the Terribore](https://biblio.co.uk/book/menace-terribore-john-mackworth/d/953025020) in 1936 (published also in the US in 1937 as [The Raid of the Terribore](https://www.biblio.com/book/raid-terribore-mackworth-john/d/951518082)). The time frame in my question was related to the abridged translated edition in the Mladá fronta (1971).
Surprisingly, there is no trace of it in Wikipedia, Goodreads, or even the major SF encyclopedias. Although it wasn't anything too extraordinary even for its time, it certainly belongs in science fiction history and by my opinion it doesn't deserve complete oblivion.

Comment: Huh. At least [ISFDB has it](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?914619). Would you like any help in building an article on Wikipedia? :) You could also put tropes for it on TVTropes.org, which is an excellent way to draw eyes.